# Conditional Result Binding

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of converting my db queries to prepared statements. Given the following scenario, how would I accomplish the result binding?

```
function getRecord($type = 1)
{
    $sql = "select field1, field2, field3";

    if ($type == 2) $sql .= ", field4, field5";

    $sql .= " from table";
    $sql .= " where field1 = 'somevalue'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $val1 = $record['field1'];
        $val2 = $record['field2'];
        $val3 = $record['field2'];

        if ($type == 2)
        {
            $val4 = $record['field4'];
            $val5 = $record['field5'];
        }
    }
}
```

In other words:

```
function getRecord($type = 1)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    $sql = "select field1, field2, field3";

    if ($type == 2) $sql .= ", field4, field5";

    $sql .= " from table";
    $sql .= " where field1 = ?";

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', 'somevalue');            
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $record['field1'],
                                        $record['field2'],
                                        $record['field3']);
        if ($type == 2)
        {
            // How do I bind the rest of the results?
        }

        if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
        {
            // Do something
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

How do I bind the rest of the results if ($type = 2)?

Comment: Your question needs to be a bit more specific than this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What else do you need to know?

Comment: @gr8dane Just check: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Devon As I said, I'm trying to convert existing queries (like my example) to prepared statements. See my edit.

Comment: @CharlesRojas I don't see an answer to my question there. See my edit.

Comment: What happens, if you are get five fields in both cases? What are you try to optimize?

Comment: @gr8dane I'm not so sure this is a valid question because with the official docs, you're just so close... check answer and please delete this question

Comment: @CharlesRojas Why would it be invalid? What do you mean by "you're just so close"?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
if ($type == 2) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result(
    $stmt,  
    $record['field1'],
    $record['field2'],
    $record['field3'],
    $record['field4'],
    $record['field5']
  );
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result(
    $stmt,  
    $record['field1'],
    $record['field2'],
    $record['field3']
  );
}
```

But why you even need this?

Comment: I guess I could just select *, but isn't there a case to be made for getting only the data you actually need? This is obviously one way (maybe the only way) to do it, but it can get bulky if $type can have more than two values, and I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way of accomplishing it.

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#82742) php.net comment.